# No such method error after trying to fetch data and turn it into list

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to receive a list of items from my backend. However I am facing one error.
I've created classes for each item inside the collection. The response looks following:

fetch function

```
  fetchAdventures() async {
    var response = await getAdventures(apiClient);
    adventureList = List<Adventures>.from(
        (response.data.collection).map((json) => Adventures.fromJson(json))
    );
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Model

```dart
class Adventures {
  bool completed;
  bool favorite;
  String id;
  String name;

  Adventures(
      {required this.completed,
      required this.favorite,
      required this.id,
      required this.name,
});

  factory Adventures.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Adventures(
        completed: json['completed'],
        favorite: json['favorite'],
        id: json['id'],
        name: json['name'],
    );
  }
}
```

The collection contains the Adventures items. Json response after the get request:

```
{"collection":[],"page":1,"page_size":50,"total_pages":1,"total_results":0}
```

```
E/flutter ( 8766): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: Class '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' has no instance getter 'collection'.
E/flutter ( 8766): Receiver: _LinkedHashMap len:5
```

Comment: Try replacing `response.data.collection` with `response.data["collection"]`

Answer (score 0):

Change `fetchAdventures` method to :

```
fetchAdventures() async {
    var response = await getAdventures(apiClient);
    final parsed = json.decode(response.data.collection).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
    adventureList = parsed
        .map<Adventures>((json) => Adventures.fromMap(json))
        .toList();
    notifyListeners();
}
```